# Written my first LSTM - looking for feedback as well as ways I can improve it's learning abilities

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have written an LSTM using Tensorflow that reads in sequences of 25 chars from a large text file of Shakespeare's plays. All charatcers are encoded to and from one-hot vectors. From what I can tell, it is working as it should be. I trained it for quite some hours, and it reached about 80% accuracy - and was still increasing when the training finished. However, when validating the model's performance on an unseen 20% of the text file, accuracy was only about 50%. Hence, I am now looking for any critiques on my code, and more so ways in which I can improve and optimise my model. Refelcting this loss in performance when using unseen data, it also produced quite a poor text of its own.

Firstly, my model would begin generating text, but quickly become stuck in a loop of repeating the same sequence of characters over and over again, never breaking the loop. To combat this problem, I added a `DropoutWrapper` with an `output_keep_prob` of 80%. This did indeed stop the model from repeatedly spitting out the same sequence of characters. However, it is still quite poor at producing any meaningful text at all - even any words at all. Some of the syntax and punctuation is decent, but nothing more.

My main questions are with regards to all the variables that can be manually tuned before training my NN. Things such as:

- the number of hidden cells
- the number of hidden layers (I haven't tried adding more yet)
- the learning rate
- the forget bias (what range of values can this take, and what does a value such as 2.0 actually mean?)
- the difference between output/input/state keep probabilities, and when to use which

How is one meant to successfully decide on the values for all of these variables, when it takes hours to test each combination?

In a nutshell, any advice on how I can increase the learning ability and overall accuracy of my model's ability to predict the next characters,  and possibly make it more efficient in doing so would be greatly appreciated. It appears to be overfitting the training data, but I am lost with how to combat this.

As a side note, despite my model clearly not working well on the validation set, I am also unsure if my `generateText()` method is the best way to go about creating its own text.

Here is my code, as well as a snippet of text produced after ~90,000 training iterations over ~6-7 hours:

**CODE:**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

text = open("/home/kev/Documents/NeuralNetworks/CharacterPredicter/shakespeare.txt", 'r').read()
#text = "abcdefghij"
vocab = list(set(text))
textSize = len(text)
vocabSize = len(vocab)
testingStartChar = int(textSize * 0.8)

charToInt = {char : i for i, char in enumerate(vocab)}
intToChar = {i : char for i, char in enumerate(vocab)}

sequenceLength = 25  # Must be strictly < (textSize / 5)
batchSize = 100

numValidationSequences = (textSize - testingStartChar - 1) // sequenceLength
epochSize = textSize // (sequenceLength * batchSize)
trainingIterations = epochSize * 200
#trainingIterations = 1000

hiddenDimension = 500
learningRate = 0.001
forgetBias = 1.0
outputKeepProb = 0.8
printStep = 100

# [batchSize, seqLength, vocabSize]
def generateData(batchSize, seqLength, isTraining, charPointer):
    inputs = []                                                 # e.g.  a, b = generateData(2, 3, True)
    labels = []                                                 #       a -> [[[0, 1, ..., 0], [1, 0, ..., 0], [0, 0, ..., 1]]
    for _ in range(batchSize):                                  #             [[1, 0, ..., 0], [0, 0, ..., 1], [0, 1, ..., 0]]]
        inputSequence = []
        labelSequence = []
        #if isTraining:
        #    charPointer = random.randint(0, testingStartChar - seqLength)  # Uncomment for random sequences
        if isTraining and charPointer + sequenceLength + 1 >= testingStartChar:
            charPointer = 0
        if not isTraining and charPointer + sequenceLength + 1 >= textSize - 1:
            charPointer = testingStartChar
        for _ in range(seqLength):
            oneHotInput = charToOneHot(text[charPointer])
            oneHotLabel = charToOneHot(text[charPointer + 1])
            inputSequence.append(oneHotInput)
            labelSequence.append(oneHotLabel)
            charPointer += 1
        inputs.append(inputSequence)
        labels.append(labelSequence)
    return inputs, labels, charPointer

# Converts a single  character into a
# one-hot vector of length vocabSize
def charToOneHot(char):
    oneHot = [0] * vocabSize
    oneHot[charToInt[char]] = 1
    return oneHot

# Converts a list of sequenceLength characters
# into a list of corresponding one-hot vectors
def charsToOneHots(chars):
    oneHots = []
    for char in chars:
        oneHots.append(charToOneHot(char))
    return oneHots

# Converts a single one-hot vector
# into a single char
def oneHotToChar(oneHot):
    charIndex = np.argmax(oneHot)
    return intToChar[charIndex]

# Converts a list of sequenceLength one-hot vectors
# into a list of corresponding characters
def oneHotsToChars(oneHots):
    chars = []
    for batchIndex in range(len(oneHots)):
        batchChars = []
        for charIndex in range(len(oneHots[batchIndex])):
            batchChars.append(oneHotToChar(oneHots[batchIndex][charIndex]))
        chars.append(batchChars)
    return chars

# Converts a 3D array of predictions of shape [batchSize, sequenceLength, vocabSize]
# into a list of one-hot vectors where the 1 corresponds to the prediction with the
# highest score. These are then converted into batchSize lists of sequenceLength
# predicted characters
def predictionsToChars(predictions):
    chars = []
    for batchIndex in range(len(predictions)):
        batchChars = []
        for charIndex in range(len(predictions[batchIndex])):
            predictionOneHot = np.zeros_like(predictions[batchIndex][charIndex])
            maxChar = np.argmax(predictions[batchIndex][charIndex])
            predictionOneHot[maxChar] = 1
            batchChars.append(oneHotToChar(predictionOneHot))
        chars.append(batchChars)
    return chars

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, sequenceLength, vocabSize])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, sequenceLength, vocabSize])
xTensors = tf.unstack(x, axis=1)                                                                # sequenceLength tensors of shape [batchSize, vocabSize]

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([hiddenDimension, vocabSize]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([vocabSize]))

cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(hiddenDimension, forget_bias=forgetBias)
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=outputKeepProb)
outputs, states = tf.nn.static_rnn(cell, xTensors, dtype=tf.float32)                            # sequenceLength list of tensors of shape [batchSize, hiddenDimension]
predictions = [tf.add(tf.matmul(output, W), b) for output in outputs]                           # sequenceLength list of tensors of shape [batchSize, vocabSize]
predictions = tf.transpose(predictions, [1, 0, 2])                                              # tensor of shape [batchSize, sequenceLength, vocabSize]

correctPredictions = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predictions, axis=2), tf.argmax(y, axis=2))             # tensor of shape [batchSize, sequenceLength], true if one-hot vector of predicted char = label
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correctPredictions, tf.float32))                              # real number in [0, 1] giving the total accuracy of predictions for this batch
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=predictions, labels=y))    # real number giving the total error in predictions for this batch
optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learningRate).minimize(loss)                                 # adjusts the paramaters based on the loss

############################################################################
#   PLOTTING
############################################################################
def plotAccuracy(x, y, iteration):      # Plots the average accuracy per 1000 iterations
    plt.axis([0, iteration, 0, 100])
    plt.xlabel("Iteration")
    plt.ylabel("Accuracy (%)")
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.plot(x, y, c='b', lw=1.0)
    plt.savefig("/home/kev/Documents/NeuralNetworks/CharacterPredicter/AccuracyGraph.png")
    plt.clf()

############################################################################
#   GENERATING
############################################################################
def generateText():
    randIndex = random.randint(0, textSize - sequenceLength)
    seedSequence = text[randIndex : randIndex + sequenceLength]
    inputOneHots = charsToOneHots(seedSequence)

    with open("/home/kev/Documents/NeuralNetworks/CharacterPredicter/output.txt", "w+") as output:
        generatedText = ""
        lineLength = 0
        for _ in range(10000):
            dict = {x: [inputOneHots]}
            pred = session.run(predictions, dict)
            predChars = predictionsToChars(pred)[0]     # [0] because in the shape of [['a', 'b', 'c', ... , 'z']]
            inputOneHots = charsToOneHots(predChars)
            if predChars[-1] == "\n":
                lineLength = 0
            elif predChars[-2] == " " and lineLength >= 70: # Keeps line length under ~70 chars
                output.write("\n")
                lineLength = 0
            lineLength += 1
            output.write(predChars[-1]) # Write most recently predicted char

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    ############################################################################
    #   TRAINING
    ############################################################################
    xPlots, yPlots = [], []     # Store points to graph average accuracy pre 1000 iteraions
    currentYPlots = []          # Stores the accuracies for the current 1000 iterations
    pointer = 0                 # Stores index of current char being read from text
    for iteration in range(trainingIterations):
        batchX, batchY, pointer = generateData(batchSize, sequenceLength, isTraining=True, charPointer=pointer)
        dict = {x: batchX, y: batchY}
        session.run(optimiser, dict)
        iteractionAccuracy = session.run(accuracy, dict)
        currentYPlots.append(iteractionAccuracy * 100)
        if (iteration + 1) % printStep == 0 or iteration in (0, trainingIterations - 1):
            #inputOneHots = session.run(x, dict)
            #labelOneHots = session.run(y, dict)
            #preds = session.run(predictions, dict)
            #correct = session.run(correctPredictions, dict)
            iterationLoss = session.run(loss, dict)
            print("Iteration:\t" + str(iteration + 1) + " / " + str(trainingIterations))
            print("Accuracy:\t" + str("%.2f" % (iteractionAccuracy * 100) + "%"))
            print("Loss:\t\t" + str(iterationLoss) + "\n")
            #print("Inputs:\n" + str(oneHotsToChars(inputOneHots)))
            #print("Labels:\n" + str(oneHotsToChars(labelOneHots)))
            #print("Prediction:\n" + str(predictionsToChars(preds)))
            #print("Correct:\n" + str(correct) + "\n")
        if ((iteration + 1) % 1000 == 0 and iteration > 0) or (iteration == trainingIterations - 1):
            yPlots.append(np.mean(currentYPlots))
            xPlots.append(iteration + 1 - 500)
            plotAccuracy(xPlots, yPlots, iteration)
            currentYPlots = []
            #generateText()

    ############################################################################
    #   VALIDATING
    ############################################################################
    testX, testY, _ = generateData(numValidationSequences, sequenceLength, isTraining=False, charPointer=testingStartChar)
    testAccuracy = session.run(accuracy, {x: testX, y: testY})
    print("Testing Accuracy: " + str("%.2f" % (testAccuracy * 100) + "%"))

    generateText()
```

**SAMPLE GENERATED TEXT:**

```
  A:
  Haug ae w.
  T:
   a offus thinoly igresure t ad o hind somanick, ile, s.
  TIfus, th, atougenigenend O:
  Meth d om wamissts he t, y,
  Sinneatined woney,
  Thotom banored ashinerenoury, wor shevis s thesusen, onisicedet oulinnane a
  bedsth ffusse.
  TI hofs aistest
  TI g
  I
  Tono tis, toning thy ars ouco ifop

  AS th anorot, idle.
  DUSenedaleth thabor oumbedr sHe t alagr
  Angoo mpinofine, tince nsths Thath,
  W berut feronenses oregonshameroete there wis thordssances th, alyon tlstinourel
  yol, aire, ago ap tr, lessesunes s at, to fofa, y'skshelfonongies tovethe, 
  anen anedaswes,
  St alarverilinssinsy As,

  Pinone!
  An, win
  Wat, ate an t,
  At t h ofune te, ones tursed inesind tend yopste ons.
  men a oystrieats:
  Tchalyodonas, ts, outhedethene tex
  Nevondeds tethededeshus anmanean, anedoneloranoush, m thn t, finedits s:
  o t y anenino b.
```

Comment: Not sure exactly why this was voted as off-topic, but I think it's because you are asking about the code. Perhaps try to reword it to focus more on content. Other than that, my experience with LSTMs is that you gain a lot of performance in how you feed the dataset: you should try to not reset the states between training examples. I found this explanation very helpful: http://machinelearningmastery.com/understanding-stateful-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/